# Generate a random number in swift and then add another number to it?

Tags: swift

How do I generate a random number in Swift language that can be used in math, such as addition. Basically I just want to be able to generate a random number and then add it to a count that I have.
For example, how would I generate a random number that I can add 1 to?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one & the **arc4random** function will generate value between 1-9 & it returns **UInt32** type value so modify it what you wanna.

```
var count : UInt32 = 10
var value : UInt32 = arc4random()%10

count += value

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `arc4random_uniform()` function because it generates a uniform distribution.

The following line generates a number from 0-9.

```
var x = Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) // Cast it to Int because function returns UInt32
println(x)
var sum = 10 + x
println(sum)
```